# Talking GPS software for Android?

Tags: gps

I need a GPS when I use ride my bike. :\
Holding my phone in my hand is not really a solution....
Can somebody help me to find a talking GPS Android app?

Thank you...

Comment: Do you want something that just tells you your location, something that gives you directions to get from A to B while you're riding, or something else?

Comment: "to get from A to B while you're riding"

Comment: well, just continue using your android phone, but use some accessories, like bluetooth headset and/or something that fixes that on your arm or on bike...

Answer (score 7):

Provided that you have a phone running Android 1.6 or higher, and are in a [supported country](http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?answer=172221), then [Google Maps Navigation](http://www.google.com/mobile/navigation/) will do this. You should have Navigation as a separate icon in your apps list (upwards pointing blue arrow icon) even though it comes with Maps. If you don't have that (and are on a supported version and in a supported country) then just go to the Market and search for the [updated version of Google Maps](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps).

I've used it for car and walking directions, and it works very well, don't need to take the phone out of my pocket while walking, as everything spoken through my headphones.

Comment: ohh bummer...my country isn't on the list... :\

Comment: Brut Google Maps has unlocked talking navigation for all countries. You can get it here:http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1007132

Comment: Note that Brut Maps is an unofficial, hacked version of Google Maps, use at your own risk.

Answer (score 3):

I swear by [Waze](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.waze).  It is gives spoken directions.  As a plus (or actually main selling point), it is a social GPS.  That is, by keeping track of speed and location, it knows where there is heavy traffic and routes you around it.