# Does automated mapping with voice come pre-defaulted in Android without needing a data plan?

Tags: gps

Navigation is yes -- [Does Android come with free navigation in non-US contries?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1854/does-android-come-with-free-navigation-in-non-us-contries)

And it has voice -- [Talking GPS software for Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9054/talking-gps-software-for-android)

But do you need a data plan?

Comment: I honestly have no idea what you're asking. What are you looking for here?

Comment: GPS doesn't use a data plan. GPS = Global Positioning Satellite. GPS (on any device) uses the same type of communication for getting the location when using GPS.

Comment: You've changed question too much...

Answer (score 3):

GPS in most of the smartphones are [aGPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assisted_GPS).

> "Standalone" or "Autonomous" GPS operation uses radio signals from
>   satellites alone. A-GPS additionally uses network resources to locate
>   and utilize the satellites in poor signal conditions.

So in my phone HTC Desire, it automatically updates some GPS system file via Internet so GPS lookup can happen quickly. However, in normal GPS operation it won't require Internet so it doesn't require a data plan.

Comment: On most (if not all) Android devices aGPS can be switched off to eliminate mobile data use on pure GPS lookups. E.g. in 4.0: `Settings` -> `Location services` -> `Google's location service` or in 2.1-2.3: `Settings` -> `Location & security settings` -> `Use wireless networks`